# WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)

Tags: hibernate

Developing a Java EE application I get the next warning:

```
WARN:   HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for     production use!)
Información:   HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL     [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/city-help-point?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull]
Información:   HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=chp, password=****}
Información:   HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Información:   HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Información:   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Información:   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Información:   HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool     [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/city-help-point?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull]
Información:   HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: chpPUN
...]
```

How can I avoid them?

Comment: by using a real connection pool not the hibernate built-in. see dbcp, hikaricp or the pool coming with you application server (tomcat, jboss, etc..)

Comment: Ok, I'll check it. Thanks!